# Passing parameters to a jquery function from a button click

Tags: jquery

I have to be able to change the colour of text via three buttons (red, blue and black)

The function I have, which works fine is as follows:

```
function btn_click() {
$("#col1 p").css("color", "#00f");
    }
```

I need to pass two variables to this function, the specific tag (e.g. col1 p) and the hex value from the following function call:

```
<input type="image" value="" class="but-blue" onclick="btn_click();" />
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 22):

Change script to:

```
function btn_click(selector, color) {
    $(selector).css("color", color);
}
```

And inline handler to:

```
<input type="image" value="" class="but-blue" onclick="btn_click('#col1 p','#00F');" />
```

**update**

But with jQuery you can do following:

```
<input type="image" value="" class="but-blue" data-selector="#col1 p" data-color="#00F" />
```

and jQuery script itself:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=image]').click(function() {
       var selector = $(this).data('selector');
       var color = $(this).data('color');

       $(selector).css("color", color);
    });
});
```

Comment: Since we are using jquery, though, we should bind the click handler to the DOM instead of using the onclick attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I've added sample with jQuery.

Comment: +1 for showing how to do it right (second part). And you can bind event handlers the right way even without jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to go full-JQuery, do the Following

```
function btn_click(selector, color) {
    $(selector).css("color", color);
}

$("input").bind("click", function(event) {
    btn_click($(this).attr("goal-selector"), $(this).attr("goal-color"));
});
```

And then in your HTML

```
<input type="image" value="" class="but-blue" goal-selector="#col1 p" goal-color="#00f" />
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

something like this? :

```
function btn_click(selector, color) {
    $(selector).css("color", color);
}
```

and the onclick function would be:

```
<input type="image" value="" class="but-blue" onclick="btn_click('#col1 p','#00f');" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Aren't this be better:

```
<input type="button" value="#00F" class="button-color"  />
<input type="button" value="#0FF" class="button-color"  />
<input type="button" value="#FFF" class="button-color"  />
<div id="you_need_to_change"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.button-color').click(function(){$('#you_need_to_change").css("color", $(this).val())});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this

```
function btn_click(selector, color) {
    $(this).css(selector, color);
}

<input type="image" value="" class="but-blue" onclick="btn_click('color','#00f');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#redColorBtn").click(function(){
  $("#urTextFiled").css("color", "#f00");
});

$("#greenColorBtn").click(function(){
  $("#urTextFiled").css("color", "#0f0");
});

$("#blueColorBtn").click(function(){
  $("#urTextFiled").css("color", "#00f");
});
```

**#** in jquery is used to catch an element on the basis of id value so all **#** related things should be the id of elements.